# Parseval's theorem.

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

We consider two signal $h(t)$ and $g(t)$ such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(t)|^2dt<+\infty$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2dt<+\infty$$
Parseval's theorem states that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{h(t)g(t)^*dt}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{H(\omega)G(\omega)^*d\omega}$$
where $^*$ is the conjugate and $H(\omega),G(\omega)$ are the Fourier Transforms.

This result is also valid if, instead of the integrals, there are the series and instead of the transforms there are the Fourier series?

Comment: Yes, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_Plancherel_theorem_and_Parseval.27s_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question follows from properties of the complex numbers. I'm assuming you're used to $j=\sqrt{-1}$ instead of $i=\sqrt{-1}$; so that's what I'll use. Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers. Then
$$
          z w^{\star} = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}j^{n}|z+j^{n}w|^{2}
$$